# Java: check pair if sum to a given number not working with negative number

Tags: java, sorting

I'm going through hyperskill and found such Java problem:

> Write a program that reads the numbers a, b, c and checks if there's a pair of them that adds up to exactly 20.

> The program must output true or false.

Now I wrote this which passes two tests: "1 2 3" and "4 16 7" but fails with a negative number. Can you help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[2];
    int howMuch = 20;
    int size = 2;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= (arrayOfNumbers.length -1); i++){
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        arrayOfNumbers[i] = number;
        }

    if (hasArrayTwoCandidates(arrayOfNumbers, size, howMuch)) {
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}

static boolean hasArrayTwoCandidates(int A[], int arr_size, int sum)
{
    int l, r;

    Arrays.sort(A);

    l = 0;
    r = arr_size - 1;
    while (l < r) {
        if (A[l] + A[r] == sum)
            return true;
        else if (A[l] + A[r] < sum)
            l++;
        else // A[i] + A[j] > sum
            r--;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: `int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[2];` How does this pass any test when the problem requires you take in 3 numbers and you are only using a size of 2?

Comment: You only read in two numbers. This is not about negative numbers.

Comment: yeah, basic error with the array size not index. thanks!

Comment: @Nexevis it did pass these two tests though because the first two numbers either added or not.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I made a basic error with the size of the array (index 2 is third element, but not the size itself). Corrected + another in the piece of code while going through indexes.
Thanks!